# Using CustomBottomSheetBehavior in an Scrolling Activity causes an empty space behind tool-bar

Tags: android, bottom-sheet

I am recently using [CustomBottomSheetBehavior](https://github.com/miguelhincapie/CustomBottomSheetBehavior) to make an googlemaps like bottom sheet behavior and it works great. I have only one problem.please look at this image
[image]

If I use it in a scrolling activity the content of tool-bar covers my list box. so I ahve to add margin-top to my list view. It works but when I draw bottomsheet up toolbar goes up and behind it, there is an empty space. This is because I have added some margin top to make my list's top visible. Is there any way to connect list's margin top to the amount of moving bottom-sheet and when It moves up decrease margin value to and when it moves down increase it?or is there any better way ?

It seems I have to develope my own TopMarginBehavior for this job but I have no idea how to do it. 
thanks

Comment: Hi dear @miguelhincapiec , Can you please help me in this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Create your own class related to the behavior you want (MarginTopBehavior)
2. Extends it from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior`
3. Now you have to focus on 2 methods: `layoutDependsOn` and `onDependentViewChanged`. With the first one you are selecting the view that your MarginTopBehavior is following, in this case is a `NestedScrollView`. With the second one you are reacting (the magic!) when the scroll get moved.

At this point you get this:

```
public class MarginTopBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;

    public MarginTopBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof NestedScrollView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {

    }
}
```

The logic to be applied in `onDependentViewChanged` is just this:
* Define the cap (min/max margin value) and controls when the margin value has reached one of those cap.
* Update margin value while the values are between the caps. In this point you have to implement an algorithm about what you want (parallax, linear, etc). That is what I'm calling `THE_MAGIC_ECC` in the next code:

```
public class MarginTopBehavior<V extends View> extends CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<V> {

    /**
     * Params of the component you want to modify the margin
     */
    private FrameLayout.LayoutParams mLayoutParams;
    /**
     * Used to access DIMENS in your project
     */
    private Context mContext;
    private int mMinYvalue;
    private int mMaxYValue;

    public MarginTopBehavior(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mContext = context;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean layoutDependsOn(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {
        return dependency instanceof NestedScrollView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onDependentViewChanged(CoordinatorLayout parent, View child, View dependency) {

        if (mLayoutParams == null) {
            mLayoutParams = (FrameLayout.LayoutParams) child.getLayoutParams();
        }


        if (dependency.getY() <= mMinYvalue) {
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 0);
            child.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
            return true;
        }
        else if (dependency.getY() > mMinYvalue && dependency.getY() <= mMaxYValue) {
            int THE_MAGIC_ECC = 1 + 2 + 3;
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, THE_MAGIC_ECC );
            child.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
            return true;
        }
        else {
            mLayoutParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, 100);
            child.setLayoutParams(mLayoutParams);
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: tell me if you got it or if you need something else.

Comment: Thanks my dear friend,I'll check it and let you know the result. thanks